# How to tokenize a Roman numeral term in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, tokenize, elasticsearch-analyzers

When creating tokenizer by registering token chars as below, Roman 'X' cannot be registered.(Test ES Version : ES6.7, ES5.6)

```
      "tokenizer": {
        "autocomplete": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 14,
          "token_chars": [
            "Ⅹ"
          ]
        }
    }
```

error log is like this

> {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"remote_transport_exception","reason":"[node02][192.168.115.x:9300][indices:admin/create]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"**Unknown**
>   **token type: 'ⅹ'**, must be one of [symbol, private_use,
>   paragraph_separator, start_punctuation, unassigned, enclosing_mark,
>   connector_punctuation, letter_number, other_number, math_symbol,
>   lowercase_letter, space_separator, surrogate,
>   initial_quote_punctuation, decimal_digit_number, digit,
>   other_punctuation, dash_punctuation, currency_symbol,
>   non_spacing_mark, format, modifier_letter, control, uppercase_letter,
>   other_symbol, end_punctuation, modifier_symbol, other_letter,
>   line_separator, titlecase_letter, letter, punctuation,
>   combining_spacing_mark, final_quote_punctuation,
>   whitespace]"},"status":400}

How can I tokenize Roman numerals into terms?

Comment: can you put an example of what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message clearly specifying that your Roman `X` isn't a valid `token type`. The error message also listing the valid options for `token type`, as shown below:

> must be one of [symbol, private_use, paragraph_separator,
>   start_punctuation, unassigned, enclosing_mark, connector_punctuation,
>   letter_number, other_number, math_symbol, lowercase_letter,
>   space_separator, surrogate, initial_quote_punctuation,
>   decimal_digit_number, digit, other_punctuation, dash_punctuation,
>   currency_symbol, non_spacing_mark, format, modifier_letter, control,
>   uppercase_letter, other_symbol, end_punctuation, modifier_symbol,
>   other_letter, line_separator, titlecase_letter, letter, punctuation,
>   combining_spacing_mark, final_quote_punctuation, whitespace]

The issue is in your syntax if you refer the official ES doc https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html for token chars, then you can understand what it means as explained below:

> Character classes that should be included in a token. Elasticsearch
>   will split on characters that don’t belong to the classes specified.
>   Defaults to [] (keep all characters).

And below it again specifies the valid values as `digit`, `letter` also the same link has some examples where they used `token_chars` with valid values.

Your issue would be resolved if you replace `X` with `letter` in your analyzer setting.